# Страница index of/

Tags: html

Здравствуйте! Загрузила сайт на сервер, но при введении домена появляется страница index of/ со ссылками на страницы сайта. Почему так происходит? Хотелось бы, чтобы сразу открывалось меню сайта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов два: либо создайте index.html (index.htm, index.php, ...), либо почитайте http://htaccess.net.ru/doc/htaccess/directoryIndex.php, если вам не нравится название index. =)

Answer (score 2):

```
.htaccess

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

ну или тот файл который нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Для общего развития: при переходе на доменное имя серверу нужно дать знать, какую именно страницу грузить, если пользователь попадает в корень домена, в настройках апача обычно описана примерно такая картина

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm index.asp
```

Значит это то, что сервер будет искать по порядку совпадения при переходе в корень домена, сначала index.php, если его нет index.html - ну и так далее.

Данную конфигурацию можно изменять локально на домене, для этого, как указал [@Shrek](/users/4597/shrek) нужно создать файл .htaccess в корне сайта, и задать свое правило "главной страницы", например так

```
DirectoryIndex myhomepage.php
```

но обычно вебмастера создают страницу index.php (index.html и тп) и не нагружают себя лишними телодвижениями.

Comment: :) красиво пишешь *жмет руку*  +1 тебе

Comment: пасиб) (10 символов)

Comment: Спасибо! Многое поняла.